# Visual Studio 2008 - Program exits immediately with F5 (start debugging)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2008

I'm having a strange issue with Visual Studio where if I start debugging it exits immediately. This started happening after changing the assembly name in the project properties. If I change the assembly name back to the previous name then the program runs fine. How can I fix this?

Here is the output when running after changing the assembly name:

```
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\DEV\SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility\SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility\bin\Release\SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsFormsIntegration\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsFormsIntegration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0xd80 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x174 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\DEV\SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility\SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility\bin\Release\SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.exe', Symbols loaded.
The program '[1632] SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility.vshost.exe: Managed' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
```

*Note: Path names above have been abbreviated to hide organization specific naming.*

Comment: It's a WPF application, but it has some hosted winforms controls.

Comment: Copy and paste what you see in the Output window into your question.

Comment: I added the output from running after changing the assembly name.

Comment: It is interesting that you're debugging but the executable from your Release configuration is being loaded. What was the prior assembly name?

Comment: The solution configuration is set to "Release". If I change it to "Debug" then it loads the Debug versions. It still has the same problem though.

Comment: I'm sure you've been reading the same things I have on this error, but it's a general access violation error. I'm curious if you have your debugger set to catch Native exceptions. And enable RPC debugging for a run, it might catch something.

Comment: I tried both, but didn't see anything new.

Comment: This problem is really strange. Changing from "SerialDeviceMaintenanceUtility" to "MaintenanceUtility" fixes the problem.

Comment: Seems like anything <= 22 characters resolves the problem. I'm not sure why.

Comment: That is so weird. I saw this article yesterday: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/e3619f20-f97d-4128-b274-94b1e3cdd211/
Because your path was <128 chars and the article was so old I didn't think it would be relevant. But apparently this issue is still hanging around.

Comment: Interesting, that seems related. I will check the length of the full path. I actually cut out a portion of the path from the output to hide some organization specific naming. In this context, it appears that may have been counter-productive in getting an answer.

Comment: @Sorax - It appears the thread you mentioned is pretty much the exact issue I'm facing. However, it looks like there is a problem with the path for anything >= 127 rather than >= 128. It looks like anything < 127 characters for the full path of the vshost.exe works fine. If you add an answer with the link. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/e3619f20-f97d-4128-b274-94b1e3cdd211/

Comment: Turns out this was exactly it -- the only difference being that if the vshost.exe is 127 for me it still fails (<= 126 characters works fine). Here is another related issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/c9ead6da-5e30-4c1d-9187-74361ae5b37a/

Comment: I opened a MSFT connect ticket here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/604075/visual-studio-2008-why-does-the-vshost-exe-have-a-full-path-limit-of-126-characters

Answer (score 0):

I would rebuild your solution after the assembly name change (clean and build).

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled to disable this 'turbo-exit' feature of VS2008 for months. It seems related to the XML files in my project. I had it fixed at one point, but then I got a new machine from IT and the problem was introduced again.

Check out Microsoft KB957912.

Comment: I installed the KB you mentioned and I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the startup object in the application settings?

Also, have you tried to set a Breakpoint at the earlymost available location (In a WPF Application, that would be your App.xaml.cs)? Sometimes you just don't realize when stuff like InitializeComponent() fails...

Last but not least, do you use Reflection in combination with the old Assembly Name (as a string)? Try searching your project for anything

I'm just guessing, this is kind of hard to tell given only the little information you provide :(

Comment: Yes, I tried setting the startup object. It didn't solve the problem. I can also do "step into" and get into my MainWindow.xaml.cs and past InitializeComponent(). I'm not using reflection by name. Just so it's clear, my program runs fine if you execute it outside of the IDE. It only has a problem when you try to debug in the IDE. In my comments I mentioned that the error is resolved by creating an assembly name <= 22 characters which I know doesn't really make any sense, but that is the behavior I see.